# "Cannot treat the scalar component '' as an indexed component"

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters, constraints, pyomo

Here is a few rows of my code for an operations planning optimization.I have 2 dictionaries for the product monthly demand .I have created two parameters with these two dictionaries. As **m** i have defined the months. After that, i want to multiply some variables with the parameters of demand(the following constraints) but there is an error **KeyError: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'tsi' as an indexed component"**
I don't know what is wrong with that. I have tried a lot of things to fix it but nothing works.

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo                                                   
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def run():
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

    Dict1 = {1:28800,2:26200,3:20900,4:12660,5:25770,6:12350,7:28200,8:26200,9:30000,10:7400,11:24000,12:22200}
    
    Dict2 = {1:5000,2:5700,3:4000,4:1540,5:9000,6:1800,7:7250,8:4000,9:8000,10:3000,11:5000,12:8100}

    model.m = pyo.Param(initialize = 12)                                                                                    
    model.k = pyo.Param(initialize=2)                                         
    model.i = pyo.Param(initialize=3)                                        
    model.j = pyo.Param(initialize=3)                                      
    model.l = pyo.Param(initialize=2)
    model.tsi = pyo.Param(initialize = Dict1)
    model.trc = pyo.Param(initialize = Dict2)

    model.setm = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.m)
    model.setk = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.k)
    model.seti = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.i)
    model.setj = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.j)
    model.setl = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.l)

def sixteenthRule(model, m):
    return ([model.g[1,m] for m in model.setm]) == ([model.trc[m] for m in range(1,13)])*([model.G[1,m] for m in model.setm]) + ([model.tsi[m] for m in range [1,13]])

def seventeenthRule(model, m):
    return ([model.g[2,m] for m in model.setm]) == ([model.trc[m] for m in range(1,13)])*([1-model.G[1,m] for m in model.setm])

def twentyeightthRule(model, m):
    return ([model.z[1,1,m] for m in model.setm]) == ([model.z[1,1,m-1] for m in model.setm]) + ([model.p[1,1,m] for m in model.setm]) - ([model.tsi[m] for m in range [1,13]])

def thirtythRule(model, m):
    return ([model.z[1,2,m] for m in model.setm]) == ([model.z[1,2,m-1] for m in model.setm]) + ([model.p[2,2,m] for m in model.setm]) + ([model.dr[2,m] for m in model.setm]) - ([model.G[1,m] for m in model.setm])*([model.trc[m] for m in range [1,13]]) + ([model.p[1,2,m] for m in model.setm])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `model.tsi` is a scalar parameter in the way you have defined it i.e. it can only take a single value e.g. 5 or 10.

The `Dict1` dictionary has multiple values though. If you need to pass all of them, depending on the exact details of your problem, you will have to first define a Pyomo `Set` for all the keys of `Dict1` like:

`model.set_tsi = pyo.RangeSet(1, 12)`

Then define the parameter as follows:

`model.tsi = model.tsi = pyo.Param(model.set_tsi, initialize = Dict1)`